# How to get no error, if a String value is entered or the number not related to the cases

Tags: java

How to get no error, if a String value is entered or the number not related to the cases.

```
switch(optionIssues) {
   case 1 : healthIssues = "Dental Problem"; ;break;
   case 2 : healthIssues = "Respiratory Diphtheria";;break;
   case 3 : healthIssues = "Mosquitoes Infections";;break;
}
```

Comment: why do you have double ;'s? and what problem do you have? as far as I can see, there's nothing wrong in this snippet

Comment: Add a `default case`

Comment: I am trying to find a solution that whenever I put a value which is not 1,2 or 3 it will loop print "Invalid Option"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent errors if an String is entered by reading the option as a String or by catching the exception like as following:

```
int optionIssues;
try {
    optionIssues = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    optionIssues = 0;
}
```

And anyway, you should have a default case in your switch:

```
switch(optionIssues){
    case 1 : healthIssues = "Dental Problem"; break;
    case 2 : healthIssues = "Respiratory Diphtheria"; break;
    case 3 : healthIssues = "Mosquitoes Infections"; break;
    default: System.out.println("Invalid option.");
}
```

Comment: I wanna have a loop which whenever I put 4, or 5, as long it is not 1,2 or 3, it will go back to the switch(option issues) again and print "Invalid option", any solution for that?

Comment: You can put all of it in a do { ... } while (optionIssues == 4 || optionIssues == 5);

Answer (score 0):

You should add a default case like that:

```
switch(optionIssues){
            case 1 : healthIssues = "Dental Problem";break;
            case 2 : healthIssues = "Respiratory Diphtheria";break;
            case 3 : healthIssues = "Mosquitoes Infections";break;
            default : break;
        }
```

You can see more about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/switch_statement_in_java.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a default case you will indicate your program what to do when none of the cases are fulfilled.

```
switch(optionIssues){
            case 1 : healthIssues = "Dental Problem"; ;break;
            case 2 : healthIssues = "Respiratory Diphtheria";;break;
            case 3 : healthIssues = "Mosquitoes Infections";;break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("Introduce an integer between 1 and 3");
                break;
        }
```

If you want to return to the switch when the user does not introduce the right option you can use a while loop with an ending condition like this one:

```
boolean exit = false;
System.out.println("Introduce number 4 to finish");

while(!exit) {
    switch(optionIssues){
            case 1 : 
                healthIssues = "Dental Problem";
                break;
            case 2 : 
                healthIssues = "Respiratory Diphtheria";
                break;
            case 3 : 
                healthIssues = "Mosquitoes Infections";
                break;
            case 4 : 
                exit = true;
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("Introduce an integer between 1 and 4, please");
                break;
        }
}
```

This way the swith will be repeated unless the user introduces option 4.
If you only want to repeat it when an incorrect number has been introduced:

```
boolean repeat= true;

while(repeat) {
    switch(optionIssues){
            case 1 : 
                healthIssues = "Dental Problem";
                repeat = false;
                break;
            case 2 : 
                healthIssues = "Respiratory Diphtheria";
                repeat = false;
                break;
            case 3 : 
                healthIssues = "Mosquitoes Infections";
                repeat = false;
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("Introduce an integer between 1 and 4, please");
                break;
        }
}
```

If the user introduce a 5, the boolean *repeat* is true so it will repeat. But in case of a correct number, *repeat* is false so it goes out.

Comment: I wanna have a loop which whenever I put 4, or 5, as long it is not 1,2 or 3, it will go back to the switch(option issues) again and print "Invalid option", any solution for that?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a solution to your problem :-)